# XPath expression will not get node list

Tags: java, xpath

I have some XML from a SOAP response from which I want to get all CRM_Company nodes but somehow I won't get any results. I've tried different expressions but I'd guess

//ns:CRM_Company

should work but it does not somehow.

The XML looks like this

```
<Soap:Envelope xmlns:Soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <Soap:Body>
      <ReadMultiple_Result xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/crm_company">
         <ReadMultiple_Result>
            <CRM_Company>               
               <No>12345</No>
               <Name>Name</Name>            
            </CRM_Company>
         </ReadMultiple_Result>
      </ReadMultiple_Result>
   </Soap:Body>
</Soap:Envelope>
```

My Java code looks like this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(XML.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            xPath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceResolver(xmlDocument));
            Vector<String> ret = new Vector<>();

            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("//ns:CRM_Company").evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                ret.add(node.getNodeValue());
            }
            System.out.println(ret);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and here is my "NamespaceResolver" class

```
public class NamespaceResolver implements NamespaceContext
{
    // Store the source document to search the namespaces
    private final Document  sourceDocument;


    public NamespaceResolver(Document document)
    {
        sourceDocument = document;
    }

    // The lookup for the namespace uris is delegated to the stored document.
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix)
    {
        if (prefix.equals(XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX)) {
            return sourceDocument.lookupNamespaceURI(null);
        } else if(prefix.equals("ns")) {
            return "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/crm_company";
        } else {
            return sourceDocument.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix);
        }
    }

    public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI)
    {
        return sourceDocument.lookupPrefix(namespaceURI);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The default namespace `xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/crm_company"` must be taken into account.Then the xpath could be something like `//ns1:CRM_Company`

Comment: Thanks, I already thought about the namespaces and tried with a NamespaceContext implementation (NamespaceResolver) but it didn't work out... I've edited my post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your namespace resolver isn't working, but I can suggest an alternative which is to use an XPath expression which doesn't require referring to the element using a qualified name. e.g.

`//*[local-name()='CRM_Company'][namespace-uri()='urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/crm_company']`

Comment: Somehow this does'nt work, I know it should - the XPath expression looks fine - but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

For now I am using [Saxon](https://www.saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml)  and got it running

```
        Processor processor = new Processor(false);
        try {
            Path path = Files.createTempFile(null, ".xml");
            try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path.toString()))) {
                bw.write(XML);
            }
            path.toFile().deleteOnExit();
            XdmNode document = processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(path.toFile());
            XPathCompiler xPathCompiler = processor.newXPathCompiler();
            XdmValue evaluate = xPathCompiler.evaluate("//*:CRM_Company", document);
            System.out.println(evaluate.toString());
        } catch (IOException | SaxonApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```